# How we can create Highcharts treegraph box layout in angular?

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6xhC.png)
Cannot find module 'highcharts/modules/treegraph' or its corresponding type declarations.

10 import HCTree from 'highcharts/modules/treegraph';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I checked the documentation but didn't found correct way to implement Highcharts Treegraph box layout it in angular.

I want this chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALXxa.png)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you need to load the `treemap` module before `treegraph`.

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import treemap from 'highcharts/modules/treemap';
import treegraph from 'highcharts/modules/treegraph';

treemap(Highcharts);
treegraph(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-kagqjy

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/treegraph-chart

Answer (score 0):

**Need to add the latest supported version of HighChart for treegraph.**

Not sure exactly which version you are using for the HighChart, its not there in 10.2.1 but if you will update to the latest, it will work

From:

```
"highcharts": "10.2.1", 
import HCTree from 'highcharts/modules/treegraph';
/*Cannot find module 'highcharts/modules/treegraph' or its corresponding 
type declarations.*/
```

To:

```
"highcharts": "11.1.0" 
import HCTree from 'highcharts/modules/treegraph'; // wokring fine
```